# remmina cannot grab keyboard events after Ubuntu 22.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 20.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 yesterday and remmina can no longer grab keyboard events. (Windows key, alt tab, etc)

Is there a setting I can tweak?

Remmina version 1.4.27+dfsg-2

Wayland.

Update:
My solution: using xfreerdp2 that seems to work ok

Comment: Are you on Wayland? See "About: Windowing system" to see that.

Comment: Yes I am on wayland

Comment: That is the reason. It will work on Xorg.

Comment: Thanks did it change from xorg to Wayland?